# how to setup the cassandra cluster in cloud

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, cluster-computing

I'm new to Cassandra. I installed Cassandra on my ec2 machine, but how can I configure Cassandra in cluster mode.

Is there any link that will be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

[Step 3: Running a cluster](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/GettingStarted) (let me know if that is not enough for you)

You should also read the last section (updated yesterday (110310) by jbellis) on [this page](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraHardware)

Answer (score -2):

I just tried this one today :

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/cassandra/

Google cloud will let you deploy a pre-configured cluster of Cassandra nodes within a few mouse clicks. When this service is not free, they still let you have a trial for 60 days.

** Another option is to follow their script on how to deploy multiple nodes cluster:
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/cassandra/deployment-details

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thx Riggs, just fixed that